# KiCad: Power with hierarchical sheets

Tags: power, kicad

I just started trying to use KiCad (complete newbie), and I have a very basic question about using power inputs with hierarchical sheets.

Let's say I want a single LED on a hierarchical sheet, while my main sheet simply contains a battery.

Should I use hierarchical labels to connect power from the main sheet to my hierarchical sheet, or is there another way?

For instance, the main sheet:

[image: main]

And the hierarchical sheet:

[image]

Is this the correct solution? I initially tried to used the `+9v` and `GND` elements in my hierarchical sheets (many of them in a single sheet), but KiCad complains that some of them are not driven.

I found lots of topics discussing this, but nothing I can really understand, nor related to hierarchical sheets.

If I need to use hierarchical labels for connecting power, then when should I use `+9v` and `GND`?

Comment: Technically, using `+9v` and `GND` ought to work. I have done so myself using the `VCC` and `GND` What is the error you're getting?

Comment: It says it is not driven. Does it mean I need to add a power flag to at least one `+9v` and `GND` in the hierarchical sheet?

Comment: In KiCad the power symbols are global throughout all the sheets. So if you add a battery in the main sheet and connect it to `+9v` and `GND` and then, did the same in the hierarchical sheet, KiCad will connect the nets when creating the net list. You don't have to use the hierarchical labels that way.

Comment: But then this requires a power flag in the hierarchical sheet right?

Comment: As far as I know, you don't necessarily have to use a power flag. But if you don't, the ERC won't like it.

Comment: Just being pedantic: The LED is shown reverse biased and thus won't make light in the above schematic. That's why it's important to use consistent, well-understood naming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that you have on your pictures will work fine. I have checked the Battery element in the library editor and it has both pins as a *passive pins*, so ERC wont complain.

If you want to use +9 V and GND elements from Power library, then you also need to add a *power flag*. In the [reference](https://docs.kicad.org/master/en/eeschema/eeschema.html#power-pins-and-power-flags) they say:

> It is common to have an error or a warning on power pins, even though all seems normal. [...] This happens because, in most designs, the power is provided by connectors that are not power sources (like regulator output, which is declared as Power out).
>
> The ERC thus won’t detect any Power out pin to control this wire and will declare them not driven by a power source.
>
> To avoid this warning you have to place a "PWR_FLAG" on such a power port.

So, using the power flags, you can make following configuration:

[image]

Regarding the hierarchical sheets, take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XD_PaSrLKBk) to learn more (browse the channel, there are lots of very useful videos for KiCad).